# libgit2 / git2go: How to get file mode of a blob?

Tags: go, libgit2

I am using the Go bindings of [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) ([git2go](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go) - [documentation on godoc.org](http://godoc.org/github.com/libgit2/git2go)) and I wonder if it's possible to get the file mode (such as "100644") of a blob.

Background: I'd like to resolve symbolic references and it seems that symbolic links have a file mode of `120000` and the contents of the symlink is the (relative) path of the original which I'd like to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just pushed a commit which adds the `Filemode` entry to the struct. I'm not quite sure why it was missed when first added.

Once you have your `var entry TreeEntry` you can use `entry.Filemode` to get the mode. There are also a few constants defined so you don't have to play with large octal numbers or the unix functions. For symlinks, it'd be `git.FilemodeLink`.

You should remember that this is about *mode* and type of entry, as git doesn't store *permissions* as such and you shouldn't read anything permission-wise into these values.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm and I'll won't mix up permissions and file modes again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from sure if I understand your question correctly. Anyway, maybe you're looking for:

[`func Lstat(name string) (fi FileInfo, err error)`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Lstat)

> Lstat returns a FileInfo describing the named file. If the file is a symbolic link, the returned FileInfo describes the symbolic link. Lstat makes no attempt to follow the link. If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

[`func Stat(name string) (fi FileInfo, err error)`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Stat)

> Stat returns a FileInfo describing the named file. If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

Comment: Not quite that I am looking for. The files in libgit2 (it's just a frontend to a git repository) exist only virtually. So (L)Stat can't be used.

Comment: @topskip: Oh, sorry. Please consult the godocs of the bindings. You haven't linked to it so I cannot check it by myself.